# Why doesn't my decrypt function work?

Tags: perl, encode, decode, encryption

This was not written by me; it was written by someone who passed it down to me. I lost contact with the author of the code. I have been using this code for a few years and just now realized this error. It seems that the letter sequence `rkey1` messes up the output.

For example `turkey1` outputs as decryption as `tur79y1`. This Perl code should output `turkey1` and not `tur79y1`:

```
$String = "turkey1";
$e = &encode_escaped(&palace_encrypt($String));
$d = &palace_decrypt(&decode_escaped("'\"".$e."\"'"));
print $d."<br>\n";

KEY REMOVED BY OWNER


sub palace_decrypt
{
    local $lastchar = 0;
    local $rc = 0;
    local @bs;
    for($i=length($_[0])-1; $i>=0; $i--) {
        local $tmp = ord(substr($_[0], $i, 1));
        $bs[$i] = $tmp ^ $palace_key[$rc++] ^ $lastchar;
        $lastchar = $tmp ^ $palace_key[$rc++];
        }

    return join("", map { chr($_) } @bs);
}

sub decode_escaped
{
    $_[0] =~ m/\"(.*)\"/;
    local $str = $1;
    $str =~ s/\\\\/\0/g;
    $str =~ s/\\"/"/g;
    $str =~ s/\\(..)/pack("c",hex($1))/ge;
    $str =~ s/\0/\\/g;
    return $str;
}


sub palace_encrypt
{
    local $lastchar = 0;
    local $rc = 0;
    local @bs;
    for($i=length($_[0])-1; $i>=0; $i--) {
        local $b = ord(substr($_[0], $i, 1));
        $bs[$i] = $b ^ $palace_key[$rc++] ^ $lastchar;
        $lastchar = $bs[$i] ^ $palace_key[$rc++];
        }
    return join("", map { chr($_) } @bs);
}

sub encode_escaped
{
    local $str = $_[0];
    $str =~ s/\\/\\\\/g;
    $str =~ s/([^A-Za-z0-9\.\\])/sprintf("\\%2.2X", ord($1))/ge;

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: Wow, "local".  This is some really old code.

Comment: -1: It's a lot to ask without further explanation / commenting.  Why don't you replace this code with the openssl library, or some other good encryption library?

Comment: The code you provided outputs "turkey1<br>" on my system (v5.10.0 x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi). What perl version (perl -v) and operating system are you using?

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to post your key material to a public forum, regardless of whether you're using a home-grown encryption algorithm or not.

Comment: Actually, I think it's not the same key that he is using because the posted key does produce the desired output (see my earlier comment), the key he is using probably does not.

Comment: Its not really an "encryption" anymore. It was back in 1995. Now the software it was trying to protect is basically open and noone works on the project. The key can be public. I have to use this method because the software requires it, I can't use SSL.

My perl-v

This is perl, v5.10.0 built for i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi
with Debian Lenny (5)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that your decode_escaped does not exactly undo what encode_escaped did. Replace it with the following and that should fix your problem.

```
sub decode_escaped
{
    $_[0] =~ m/\"(.*)\"/;
    local @str = split /(\\\\)/, $1;
    foreach (@str) {
        s/\\"/"/g;
        s/\\(..)/chr(hex($1))/ge;
        s/\\\\/\\/;
    }
    return join '', @str;
}
```